# JQuery - Duplicating drag and drop object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When I drag my proposed item the clone helper is dragged and the original object is left in its place, but cannot be dragged again after. I need to be able to drag the same object twice.How can I do this?

```
$('.drag').draggable({
helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: function(droppable) {
    if (droppable === false) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
});

 $('.drop').droppable({
     drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.fadeOut(1000);
     }
});

$('.drag').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: "0.8"
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: "1"
    });
});

$('.drop').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable[10, 10].id) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/qfywP/2/

The problem was with this line:

`$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable())`

You should first clone the helper, append it to the DOM, and then make it draggable:

`ui.helper.clone().appendTo($(this)).draggable()`

You should also be aware that your code was wrapped in an if statement `if (ui.draggable[10, 10].id) {}` . This wasn't returning true, and so your code was never being executed.

I also did some spring cleaning of your code, as you had some redundancies. `$('.drop').droppable()` was being declared twice, when you only needed it once.